# Is there relationship between propensity score based causal inference and sampling weights?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, causality, propensity-scores, survey-weights, weighted-sampling

Consider observational study with single outcome $Y$, single covariate $X$ and treatment assignment variable $W$. Under unconfounded treatment assignment assumption, $E_{sp}[Y(1)]=E[\frac{Y_i^{obs}W_i}{e(X_i)}]$ as shown in Rubin, Imbens' Causal Inference in 12.4, where $E[\cdot]$ means expectation taken over both randomization of treatment assignments and sampling from super population.

If I denote $R_i$ as sampling indicator to indicate subject is sampled from super population, then technically $E[\frac{Y_i^{obs}W_i}{e(X_i)}]$ should be written as $E[\frac{R_iY_i^{obs}W_i}{e(X_i)}]$ as I sampled subject $i$ from some fixed super population.

It seems that $e(X_i)$ looks like a sampling weight as in survey sampling.

$Q:$ Is it correct to think $e(X_i)$ as sampling weight? If so, what is the interpretation? What is the "population" sampled from with weights $e(X_i)$ here? This would be different from observed data population for sure, if this had not been RCT.

$Q':$ If $Q$ is correct, then causal inference in the book and Robbins' IPTW were based upon designed based inference? Hence this invalidates lm regression result on matched data with weights.

Comment: Interesting question, but I can't begin to answer without the book unfortunately. I'm familiar with most the terms from Rubin's old papers. But what is $e(X_i)$?

Comment: @AdamO $e(X_i)$ is the propensity score of subject $i$ with covariate $X_i$.